# Received NaN for the `value` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string

Tags: reactjs

I m getting this error :
1.Warning: Received NaN for the `value` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string.
2.Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
Here is my code:

```
const BASE_URL = `http://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?access_key=${ACCESS_KEY}`

const App = () => {
  const [ currencyOptions, setCurrencyOptions ] = useState([]);
  const [ fromCurrency, setFromCurrency] = useState()
  const [toCurrency, setToCurrency] = useState()
  const [exchangeRate, setExchangeRate] = useState()
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(1)
  const [amountInFromCurrency, setAmountInFromCurrency] = useState(true)

  let toAmount, fromAmount
  if (amountInFromCurrency){
    fromAmount = amount
    toAmount = amount * exchangeRate
  } else {
    toAmount =amount
    fromAmount = amount / exchangeRate
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(BASE_URL)
      .then(res => res.json())  
      .then(data => {
           const firstCurrency = Object.keys(data.rates)[0]
           setCurrencyOptions([data.base, ...Object.keys(data.rates)])
           setFromCurrency(data.base)
           setToCurrency(firstCurrency)
           setExchangeRate(data.rates[firstCurrency])
       })
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
     if (fromCurrency != null && toCurrency != null) {
       fetch(BASE_URL)
     .then(res => res.json()) 
     .then(data => setExchangeRate(data.rates[toCurrency]))
    }   
  },[fromCurrency,toCurrency])

  function handleFromAmountChange(e) {
    setAmount(e.target.value)
    setAmountInFromCurrency(true)
  }

  function handleToAmountChange(e) {
    setAmount(e.target.value)
    setAmountInFromCurrency(false)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Convert</h1>
       <CurrencyRow 
       currencyOptions={currencyOptions}
       selectedCurrency={fromCurrency}
       onChangeCurrency={e => setFromCurrency(e.target.value)}
       onChangeAmount={handleFromAmountChange}
       amount = {fromAmount}
       />
      <div className="equals"> = </div>
       <CurrencyRow 
        currencyOptions={currencyOptions}
        selectedCurrency={toCurrency}
        onChangeCurrency={e => setToCurrency(e.target.value)}
        onChangeAmount={handleToAmountChange}
        amount = {toAmount}
        />
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

And this is CurrencyRow:

```
const CurrencyRow = (props) => {
    const {
        currencyOptions,
        selectedCurrency,
        onChangeCurrency,
        amount,
        onChangeAmount
    } = props
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="number" className="input" value={amount} onChange={onChangeAmount}/>
            <select value={selectedCurrency} onChange={onChangeCurrency}>
                {currencyOptions.map(option => (
                    <option key={option.id} value={option}>{option}</option>
                ))}
            </select>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CurrencyRow;
```

Comment: What is the value of `data.rates[firstCurrency]` ? (inside `setExchangeRate(data.rates[firstCurrency])`). And is it a `string` or a `number` ?

Comment: And what the `option` object looks like ?

Comment: value of data.rates[firstCurrency] is from Api in which value varies according to country's currency.

Comment: and its value that is EUR=1 in the api

Comment: Can you try to log `typeof`  `amount` and `exchangeRate` when you define `toAmount` and `fromAmount` ? To know why `amount` is `NaN`

Comment: Actually i am newbie to know what's actually happening. So can elaborate so that i can understand

Comment: For the first warning, it says that it received `NaN` for the `value` attribute. So I suppose this is error happens in the `<input>` of `type="number"`, in which `amount` is passed as the `value`. So that means that `amount` is not a number. It may be because `amount` or `exchangeRate` is not a number, so you can check it by logging their type in console (`console.log(typeof amount, typeof exchangeRate))`. I'm really not sure but it may be the reason

Comment: it prints number number in the console

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I managed to redo the error and I think I've found the solution.

**1. Solve the issue "`Nan` for the `value` attribute"** 
Here, you check if `fromCurrency` and `toCurrency` aren't null. But actually when you render your App component for the first time, `fromCurrency` and `toCurrency` are **undefined** (and undefined ≠ null) : so `exchangeRate` will be set to `data.rates[undefined]`, which is of course `undefined`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (fromCurrency != null && toCurrency != null) {
        fetch(BASE_URL)
            .then(res => res.json()) 
            .then(data => {
                setExchangeRate(data.rates[toCurrency])
            })
     }   
},[fromCurrency,toCurrency])
```

So when you will define `toCurrency` and `fromCurrency`, you will multiply or divide numbers by `undefined`, that's why it will return `NaN` :

```
toAmount = amount * exchangeRate // 1 * undefined → NaN

fromAmount = amount / exchangeRate // 1 / undefined → NaN
```

So to solve this you can instead of checking if `fromCurrency` and `toCurrency` are `null`, check if they are `undefined` :

```
if (fromCurrency !== undefined && toCurrency !== undefined) {
    // ...
}
```

**2. Solve the issue "Each child in a list should have a unique `key` prop"** 
Here, when you map through `options`, you set the `key` attribute of each `option` to `option.id` :

```
{currencyOptions.map(option => (
    <option key={option.id} value={option}>{option}</option>
))}
```

But if you log `currencyOptions`, you can see that they are just strings ("AUD", "CAF", "CHF",...), so they don't have any `id` property, because they are not objects. So `option.id` is `undefined`. But there is another way to set a unique `key` value on each `option` : `.map()` allows you to get an `index` on each iteration :

```
<select value={selectedCurrency} onChange={onChangeCurrency}>
    {currencyOptions.map((option, index) => (
        <option key={index} value={option}>{option}</option>
    ))}
</select>
```

[image: Edit react-errors-nan-value-key-prop-required]

Hope this solved your problem !

Comment: Thanks, that 2nd error of key is vanished but the value attribute error is still there..

Comment: @stranger Yes I made a mistake, the first solution (set `fromCurrency` and` toCurrency` to `null`) of the first problem does not work. I've updated my post and here is a [sandbox] (https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-sea-xt3ed?file=/src/App.js) where the issue vanished.

Comment: Yeah...error is vanished thank you for your help @pierre-lgb...i think you are experienced in Reactjs. can you guide me to understand react ? If Yes plz share your any social media account..